# Emailing HTML form with a user input subject

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, html-email

my first post here. I've been trying to create and emailable HTML form that will send information to an internal ticketing system. The form needs to contain specific pieces of information - hence the form menus - and a subject where people can write the description. Right now, I've tried to create an email template using outlook for the purposes but I haven't found a way to make my information show up correctly.

Instead I've just been using an HTML java script form but I can't quite get it to allow the user to both change the subject and send the information from the form. Can anyone help? I'm willing to have a go at any method of sending the form that people think might work, my current approch is kind of awkward.

Current non-functional attempt. I'm fairly new at this and any help, direction or linking me to a place where I might find stuff that could help me work this out would be appreciated.

Edit: I should add that the html form is running locally on people's machines, I suspect this means that I'd have to install any languages people would use to do this via a server on every computer that uses the form, not tried this though.

Edit 2: Update, trying jquery, but isn't working. Not used before at all. Looking online now but can anyone save me some time and tell me what stupid mistake am I making that's invalidating this?

Edit 3: Fixed syntax, still not working though

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js">
$(function (){
$("#test").submit(function (){
$(this).attr('action','mailto:test@email.com?subject=' + $("#sub").val());
});
});    
</script>
</head> 

<body>

<form method="get" enctype="text/plain" id="test">
  <input type = "text" name = "sub" id = "sub" size = "44">
  <select name="Test">
   <option value="test1">test1</option>
   <option value="test2">test2</option>
   <option value="test3">test3</option>
   <option value="test4">test4</option>
  </select>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html

Answer (score 0):

You could look into the PHP mail function:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mail.php

But also, look into why that is a bad idea, there are potential security risks:
[Why shouldn't I use PHP's mail() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565066/why-shouldnt-i-use-phps-mail-function)

Answer (score -1):

With [Jquery](http://www.jquery.com) it's very easy

```
<form method="get" enctype="text/plain" id="test">
  <input type = "text" name = "sub" id = "sub" size = "44">
  <select name="Test">
   <option value="test1">test1</option>
   <option value="test2">test2</option>
   <option value="test3">test3</option>
   <option value="test4">test4</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

[Jquery](http://www.jquery.com)

```
$(function (){
 $("#test").submit(function (){
    $(this).attr('action','mailto:test@email.com?subject=' + $("#sub").val());
 });
});
```

But I would advice you to use server side client mailing. [Example with php](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mail.asp)

Comment: I imagine it was the guy who wrote the correction, I can't even do it yet :p