# Mail() only sending first word from subject

Tags: php, email

When i send some email, it only sends the first word from the subject:

Example: I send an email with the name of "Send email", it only sends the word "Send", how can i prevent that?

Code:

The subject is selected in a select box

```
<td><a>
<?=  ' '.$val['email'].'  '; ?>
<input type="text" value="<?=  $val['email']; ?>" name="to"/>
</a></td>

<td>
<select name="subject">
<?php
  foreach($templatesarr as $val){
   echo '<option value='.$val['name'].'>'.$val['name'].'</option>';
  }
  echo '</select></td>
  <td><input type="submit" name="send" value="Send e-mail" /></td>
  </td></tr>
  ';
  ?>
  </form>
```

Check if the button was clicked

```
if(isset($_POST['send'])){
$sendername = 'Company';
$from = 'noreplay@compaty.com';
$to      = safe($_POST['to']);

$subject =  safe($_POST['subject']);
$message = 'teste';

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "From: $sendername <$from>".PHP_EOL;

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

}else{
$to = NULL;

}
```

Safe function

```
function safe($value) {
    return mysql_real_escape_string($value);
}
```

Comment: Show the code for your `safe()` function. We can't do anything without seeing that.

Comment: safe is the same thing as mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string()` is almost certainly the wrong function to use.

Comment: i already tried to remove the mysql real escape string, but even without this function, it only sends the first word from the subject

Comment: On a side-note you should read **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4565066/1401094)**

Comment: I know that mail() isn't the best way to send emails in PHP, and i should download a library, but i'm only using mail() to do a simulation for my final project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is caused by *not escaping* variables and *not properly encapsulating* your attribute values; use this instead:

```
foreach($templatesarr as $val){
   printf('<option value="%1$s">%1$s</option>', 
       htmlspecialchars($val['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
   );
}
```

It now uses `""` to delimit the value attribute of the option element.

Comment: In case this was too cryptic, Jack says make sure your HTML uses `""` for the attributes. Thus making `<option value=this is my subject>` into `<option value="this is my subject">`

Comment: Jack, can you explain me what the %1$s does?

Comment: @user3726150 It's explained in [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php#example-4965).