# Codeigniter Emailer Send Email Functions Mail Spam Issue

Tags: codeigniter, email, spam

Hi I am using COdeigniter framework for my app , i which i am sending email to all our members once by using Email function ,
but on gmail email are goes in spam where yahoo and other are working well for me , is there any solution

Comment: Use domain email as from or to email address. if your domain is example.com then use email like info@example.com

Comment: Switch to SMTP. There are many reasons not to use mail();
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565066/why-shouldnt-i-use-phps-mail-function

Comment: Thanks, now i am using Third party SMTP service